# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'. unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, timer, unrecognized-selector

I have `timerRunner()` function that runs when button is clicked:

```
func timerRunner() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: target.self, selector: (#selector(self.timeUpdater)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

Selector of `Timer.scheduledTimer` is selected as following:

```
@objc func timeUpdater() {
    counter = counter + 1

    timerLabel.text = secondConverter(seconds: counter)

}
```

But this is an error message I get:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue timeUpdater]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance '

Comment: What is `target.self` in your code? Why not simply `self` as you use `#selector(self.timeUpdater)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `timeUpdater` function should have one argument of type `Timer`.
Something like that:

```
@objc func timeUpdater(_ timer: Timer) {
    counter = counter + 1
    timerLabel.text = secondConverter(seconds: counter)
}
```

Comment: Not compulsory.